# Invoke-Command with CredSSP, error: "Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters."

Tags: powershell

See Code below, Why doesn't the second Invoke-Command work?  This command gives me the error:

```
PS C:\Users\dude\Desktop\scripts> .\setup2.ps1
=> 1
Invoke-Command : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At C:\Users\dude\scripts\setup2.ps1:19 char:1
+ Invoke-Command @parameters
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

The code:

```
$machine    = "pv3039.mydomain.com"
$credential = Get-Credential -Credential "$env:userdomain\$env:username"

Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client -DelegateComputer $machine -Force | out-null

$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName $machine

Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Server -Force}  | out-null

$parameters = @{
  Session        = $s
  ScriptBlock    = { Get-Item \\copper\prj_342423 }
  Authentication = "CredSSP"
  Credential     = $credential #"$env:userdomain\$env:username"
}

write-host "=> 1"
Invoke-Command @parameters
write-host "=> 2"
```

What I don't get is that this code is taken directly from microsoft's Invoke-Command Documentation on their website.. So It should work right?  See Snapshot picture as proof:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That example is buggy. The session stored in `$s` is *already established* - you can't change its connection parameters after the fact.

Either use `-ComputerName Server02` with the other parameters you've supplied:

```
$parameters = @{
  ComputerName   = 'Server02'
  ScriptBlock    = { Get-Item \\copper\prj_342423 }
  Authentication = "CredSSP"
  Credential     = $credential #"$env:userdomain\$env:username"
}

Invoke-Command @parameters
```

... or establish a new session using Credssp with `New-PSSession -Authentication`:

```
$s2 = New-PSSession Server02 -Authentication Credssp

$parameters = @{
  Session        = $s2
  ScriptBlock    = { Get-Item \\copper\prj_342423 }
}

Invoke-Command @parameters
```

Comment: if you put -computername wouldn't that just implicitly open another session and close it after the command completes?   I'm just wondering if it runs in parallel with the current session $s?  Also, if you open a new session would the "Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Server -Force" still be in effect since it corresponds to the last session?

Comment: `Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Server` enables CredSSP _on the server_, not for the specific calling session. "if you put -computername wouldn't that just implicitly open another session and close it after the command completes?" yes, that is correct. The point is = you need to establish a new session if you want to authenticate using CredSSP

Answer (score -1):

My conclusion is that you shouldn't use microsoft's example for doing this.  Use this code instead:

```
$machine    = "pv3039.somewhere.com"
$credential = Get-Credential -Credential "$env:userdomain\$env:username"

Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client -DelegateComputer $machine -Force | out-null

$parameters = @{
  Computer       = $machine
  ScriptBlock    = { Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Server -Force }
}

Invoke-Command @parameters  | out-null

$parameters = @{
  Computer       = $machine
  ScriptBlock    = { Get-Item \\copper\someprj }
  Authentication = "CredSSP"
  Credential     = $credential #"$env:userdomain\$env:username"
}

write-host "=> 1"
Invoke-Command @parameters
write-host "=> 2"
```